# Using both GNU Utils with Mac Utils in bash

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I am working with plotting extremely large files with N number of relevant data entries. (N varies between files).

In each of these files, comments are automatically generated at the start and end of the file and would like to filter these out before recombining them into one grand data set.

Unfortunately, I am using MacOSx, where I encounter some issues when trying to remove the last line of the file. I have read that the most efficient way was to use head/tail bash commands to cut off sections of data. Since head -n -1 does not work for MacOSx I had to install coreutils through homebrew where the ghead command works wonderfully. However the command,

```
tail -n+9 $COUNTER/test.csv | ghead -n -1 $COUNTER/test.csv  >> gfinal.csv
```

does not work. A less than pleasing workaround was I had to separate the commands, use ghead > newfile, then use tail on newfile > gfinal. Unfortunately, this will take while as I have to write a new file with the first ghead.

Is there a workaround to incorporating both GNU Utils with the standard Mac Utils?

Thanks,
Keven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your command is that **you specify the file operand *again* for the `ghead` command, instead of letting it take its input from *stdin*, via the pipe**; this causes `ghead` to *ignore* stdin input, so t**he first pipe segment is effectively ignored**; simply omit the file operand for the `ghead` command:

```
tail -n+9 "$COUNTER/test.csv" | ghead -n -1 >> gfinal.csv
```

---

That said, if you only want to drop the *last* line, there's no need for *GNU* `head` - OS X's own BSD `sed` will do:

```
tail -n +9 "$COUNTER/test.csv" | sed '$d' >> gfinal.csv
```

`$` matches the last line, and `d` deletes it (meaning it won't be output).

Finally, as @ghoti points out in a comment, you could do it *all* using `sed`:

```
sed -n '9,$ {$!p;}' file
```

Option `-n` tells `sed` to only produce output when explicitly requested;  `9,$` matches everything from line `9` through (`,`) the end of the file (the last line, `$`), and `{$!p;}` prints (`p`) every line in that range, except (`!`) the last (`$`).

Comment: @ghoti: Excellent point, thank you; I've updated the answer, though I've chosen a variant that in my mind better expresses the intent.

Comment: Ah, I deleted my comment in order to expand it into an answer. :)  Your new sed script expresses the goal of the OP with greater poetry, but I don't think it does so more clearly. This way, it says "print lines that meet these criteria" rather than just "delete these ranges of lines from the stream". I would suggest that they are simply different perspectives on the problem.  (But +1 for your great explanation, as usual.)

Comment: @ghoti: Thanks; point taken re different perspectives. I will say, though, that my `sed` command  more closely resembles the _OP_'s approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both of your responses! If I were not using the MacOSx, I would be allowed to use "tail | head". Why is it a different case for ghead?

Also, in the case where the files have ~1 million entires, is there a method of removing the last line without actually reading the data? From what I have read on other stackexchange posts that head | tail method is the most efficient.

Comment: @kevenren: You just need to remove the `$COUNTER/test.csv` argument from the `ghead` command to make your overall command work (this is what I tried to explain at the beginning of my post).

Comment: Holy, I just realised the error. Thanks! I've been staring at the code for ages wondering why it did not work! (such a embarrassing rookie mistake)

Comment: @kevenren: No worries - I didn't see it either when I first answered. As for efficiency: a possible optimization would be for `ghead` to start reading from the _end_ of the file with a negative line-number argument,
but that only makes sense if the number falls into the _lower_ half of the file - and without reading the whole file and counting lines, you can't know if that's the case,
so this optimization is not an option (except if you assume that for low numbers the end is a better starting point, with a heuristically defined threshold).
How `ghead` truly operates, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that your question is about using `head` and `tail`, but I'll answer as if you're interested in solving the original problem rather than figuring out how to use those particular tools to solve the problem. :)

One method using `sed`:

```
sed -e '1,8d;$d' inputfile
```

At this level of simplicity, GNU sed and BSD sed both work the same way.  Our sed script says:

- `1,8d` - delete lines 1 through 8,
- `$d` - delete the last line.

If you decide to generate a sed script like this on-the-fly, beware of your quoting; you will have to escape the dollar sign if you put it in double quotes.

Another method using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>9{print last} NR>1{last=$0}' inputfile
```

This works a bit differently in order to "recognize" the last line, capturing the previous line and printing after line 8, and then NOT printing the final line.

This awk solution is a bit of a hack, and like the sed solution, relies on the fact that you only want to strip ONE final line of the file.

If you want to strip more lines than one off the bottom of the file, you'd probably want to maintain an array that would function sort of as a buffered FIFO or sliding window.

```
awk -v striptop=8 -v stripbottom=3 '
  { last[NR]=$0; }
  NR > striptop*2 { print last[NR-striptop]; }
  { delete last[NR-striptop]; }
  END { for(r in last){if(r<NR-stripbottom+1) print last[r];} }
' inputfile
```

You specify how much to strip in variables. The `last` array keeps a number of lines in memory, prints from the far end of the stack, and deletes them as they are printed. The `END` section steps through whatever remains in the array, and prints everything not prohibited by `stripbottom`.

Comment: Good point re double-quoting; your `awk` command should say `NR>9`, and could be optimized by replacing `NR>1` with `NR>=9`, or, more generally: `n=9; awk "NR>$n{print last} NR>=$n{last=\$0}" inputfile` - but, as you state, this is a bit hacky.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the awk one-liner, and yes, that would be an optimization. Re your general approach, notwithstanding other considerations, I don't think I would ever use double quotes to contain an awk script -- I'm afraid of variable expansions inside scripts like that. I would be more inclined to: `awk -v n="$n" 'NR>n{print last} ...`.

Comment: Yes, good point re variable passing - using `-v` is the way to go. I just took a shortcut in this simple case.